# Hosting Chromium Embedded in Mac Application

Tags: c#, c++, macos, mono, chromium-embedded

We have an application that currently hosts the Chromium Embedded Framework in a Windows application. A lot of our application is written in C#, but CEF is hosted in C++, using C++/CLI.

We are looking at the best way to make this available on OS-X. I'm hoping, in time, to use C# via Mono or .Net Core, but I am wondering how we might host chromium embedded. Does anyone have any experience of creating a cross-platform app using CEF? Any pointers on how to get going?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/chromiumfx/chromiumfx/issues/9/mono-support

Answer (score 1):

You should choose correct C# bindings for CEF, which is not rely to C++/CLI. It is CefGlue or probably ChromiumFX (sorry, i'm don't look deeply into chromiumfx).

You can try to check this fork of Xilium.CefGlue: https://bitbucket.org/icenium/xilium.cefglue/commits/branch/xilium.cefglue.monomac .

I'm personally do not use mac, so it is all what's i'm can help.